# pywinauto: срок жизни оболочек

Tags: pywinauto

Для ускорения поиска оболочек мы помещаем их в словарь вида:

```
[wrapper.element_info.name] = wrapper
```

Было замечено, что, по мере работы с управляемым приложением, оболочки начинают вести себя так, как будто теряют значимость: например, некоторые кнопки перестают нажиматься, если взять оболочку из словаря. Почему так?

Comment: Ваш комментарий не конструктивен. Мы тут обсуждаем решение технических проблем, а не знание английского языка. И, если вы не заметили, это русскоязычная версия портала.

Comment: Отличное уточнение про "русскоязычную". Что такое "враппер" в русском языке? Я вот не понимаю, мне вопрос не понятен в целом. Вот wrapper, понимаю, а про "враппер" нет. Как мне быть? Голосовать за закрытие вопроса или указать пользователю на то, что это "русскоязычная" площадка?

Comment: Знаете, в русском сейчас достаточно много англицизмов. В чём-то я вас понимаю. Но всё-таки, как по мне, вы раздуваете из мухи слона. Любой программист знает что такое wrapper, и уж извините, если вас как-то задел факт того, что я написал это слово по-русски.

Comment: @edem в данном контексте понятно, что такое враппер/вроппер/wrapper, а вот что такое оболочка - совсем не понятно. Можно, конечно, использовать wrapper как есть, но использование английских слов не удобно тем, что они не склоняются. Так что первоначальный вариант "врапперов" как раз был самым понятным и читаемым.

Comment: @insolor кому как. Это личное мнение. Кому-то не понравится слово словарь, например, вместо другого английского слова. А городить русские окончания к английским окончаниям (-er: wrap-er) курам насмех по моему скромному (не очень) мнению, лучше уж подружиться со словарём иностранных (английских) слов. Умные люди же тут собрались.

Comment: @edem проблема в том, что словари пополняются медленнее, чем возникает необходимость в новых словах. В данном случае (по моему также не очень скромному мнению) проще подстроить язык под свои нужды, чем использовать неподходящий перевод "оболочка". Язык - это всего лишь инструмент, а не святая корова, которую нужно непременно держать в чистоте от иностранных заимствований.

Comment: @insolor в 8-и случаях из 9-и они УЖЕ пополнены, достаточно в них заглянуть, а не выдавать невежество в переводе на русский (знании иностранного языка) за "подстроение под свои нужды". ПС. В чистоте нужно держать не только язык, но и ротовую полость в целом.

Comment: @edem 1 - почему сейчас не тот самый 9-й случай? 2 - про ротовую полость это вообще к чему?

Comment: @insolor 1) Потому что у этого слова уже есть перевод. Напомню как в английском строятся слова: глагол (действие) + окончание -er = тот, кто делает действие, либо итог действия. Пример: write -- писать, writer -- писатель; cut -- резать; cutter -- резец (нож); wrap -- обёртывать; wrapper -- обёртыватель, обёртка, оболочка. 2) Пример действительной пользы для носителя, когда чистый язык, ротовая полость, в целом, зубы, свежее дыхание и всё такое прочее. Пример с языком, который не корова, не особо понятен, почему нет?

Comment: @edem 1) обёртка - допускаю, оболочка - не очень подходящий вариант (IMHO). Переводить "writer" как "писатель" в контексте программирования - так себе вариант, потому что в "писатель" в русском языке означает конкретно человека-писателя. 2) Это вообще какая-то дичь пошла, проигнорирую.

Comment: @insolor где ж такие доводы были (про "в русском языке означает") когда в обиход пришли такие слова как: рабочий стол, мышь, обои. А как англоговорящие додумались ошибку назвать жуком и глазом не моргнули? Ух, удивительные люди. ПС. Думаю на этом и завершим обсуждение, всё равно сносить будут дальше, ибо не по делу вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если приложение динамическое и пересоздаёт какие-то элементы, то очевидно, что на стороне Python скрипта "ссылки" на них протухают. Если хочется надёжности или устойчивости к перезапуску, то надо хранить спецификации окна, хотя за это и придётся заплатить повторным поиском каждый раз. Кэширование врапперов внутри спецификации окна у нас не реализовано, так что этот вопрос остаётся на пользователе. А вот ссылка на объект Application в спецификации окна хранится, поэтому если сделать .connect(...) к другому экземпляру того же приложения, спецификации окна продолжат находить нужные элементы. Это как раз было реализовано по запросу одного из пользователей в GitHub issues.

P.S. Надеюсь, ответы помогают. Об этом хорошо бы сигнализировать, помечая верные ответы как принятые (слева от ответа есть серый чек бокс, он работает независимо от репутации). Ну, и заодно это поддерживает мотивацию к дальнейшим ответам.

P.P.S. Привет из Нижнего.